# Android KeyStore Encrypt and Decrypt Data

Tags: java, android, encryption, kotlin, android-keystore

My problem is this: I am trying to encrypt some user's sensitive data before save it into my Database. Encryption was not a problem, the problem begins in the decryption part.

I got this:

```
07-22 16:25:38.941 18035-18035/io.nourish.strongerasfukk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.nourish.strongerasfukk, PID: 18035
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.nourish.strongerasfukk/io.nourish.strongerasfukk.Register}: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:692)
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:712)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:263)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:108)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:612)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:532)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getSpi(Cipher.java:437)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:815)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:774)
    at **io.nourish.strongerasfukk.utilities.Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.kt:28)
    at io.nourish.strongerasfukk.Register.onCreate(Register.kt:54)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible padding mode
    at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:632)
    at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:712) 
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54) 
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89) 
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:263) 
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:108) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:612) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:532) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getSpi(Cipher.java:437) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:815) 
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:774) 
    at io.nourish.strongerasfukk.utilities.Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.kt:28) 
    at io.nourish.strongerasfukk.Register.onCreate(Register.kt:54) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

As you can see, the problem reference this two lines of code, which are:

Encryption.kt (line 28)

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
```

&

Register.kt (line 54)

```
var decryptedData = encryption.decrypt(encryptedData,masterKey?.private)
```

I've tried to put in the Cipher.init the provider or without the provider and got the same error; I've sought on the web or over here for some solutions but got nothing. What I am missing or doing wrong? Also, I tried the example over here ([Link](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/)) without any result as well.

I got the code example from this link ([link](https://proandroiddev.com/secure-data-in-android-encryption-in-android-part-2-991a89e55a23)) but had to modify some things to my own purporses.

Here is my code, for better understanding.

KeyStoreAdapter.kt

```
class KeyStoreAdapter {

private val kS = createAndroidKeyStore()

fun checkIfKeyExists(key: String) {
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply { load(null) }
    val alias = keyStore.aliases().toList()

    if(!alias.contains(key)) {
        val kpg: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")
        val parameterSpec: KeyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MasterKeys", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .build()
        kpg.initialize(parameterSpec)
        kpg.generateKeyPair()
    }
}

fun getKeys(alias: String): KeyPair? {
    val privateKey = kS.getKey(alias, null) as PrivateKey?
    val publicKey = kS.getCertificate(alias)?.publicKey

    return if(privateKey != null && publicKey != null) {
        KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)
    } else {
        null
    }
}

private fun createAndroidKeyStore(): KeyStore {
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keyStore.load(null)
    return keyStore
}
```

}

Encryption.kt
class Encryption {

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.TRANSFORMATION)

fun encrypt(data: String, key: Key?): String {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val bytes = cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray())
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
}

fun decrypt(data: String, key: Key?): String {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)
    val encryptedData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val decodedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)
    return String(decodedData)
}
```

}

```
const val TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"
```

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: 1. Does the code at the link work for you without error? If so go back to it and add your changes one-by-one until you get a failure. Then examine that one change carefully. 2. Why are you using RSA, an asymmetric cipher, instead of a symmetric cipher such as AES? Asymmetric ciphers such as RSA are slow and can only encrypt short data (less than the key size), symmetric ciphers such as AES are fast and can encrypt essentially data of unlimited size.

Comment: Hey, @zaph. Thanks for your response. No, the code didn't work for me either; that's why I tried to make some modifications and to thought I would work. The code stopped, as well, in the decrypt part. I will try AES then and see what happens. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: weird package name

Comment: @war_Hero could be the package name the problem? ..

Comment: nope its a mouthful that's all

Comment: Lol, thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: Here is the keystore based encryption explained in detail https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2021/07/android-keystore-based-encryption-and.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use padding as "OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding". It is supported from SDK 10+. 
Code:

`const val TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding"`

Generate key

```
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")
keyPairGenerator.initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT
                    or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
.setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
.setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1) 
.build())
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible. Thanks for your response, @Kislingk